# Good way to notify distributor that the worker can't process any more messages

Tags: go, amazon-sqs

I currently have a distributor service and a worker service that communicate via SQS. The distributor searches for expired values in a postgresql database and sends them to SQS.

The worker picks up jobs from SQS and calls an API to get more data. This API has a quota limit.

When the worker reaches this quota what is the best way to notify the distributor that no more work should be sent?

My initial ideas:

- Go back into postgres and reinsert the data with a much later expiration date such that the next time it is processed I will surely have enough quota units. (I have to do this anyway as there are 3 requests to get all the data and failing 1/3 means I would have to reinsert the job).
- Send a stop signal through the queue that the distributor will receive. The only issue to get around here is that I would not want the message to stay in the queue longer than needed, and having more than one distributor running at the same time complicates message consumption.
- Check the size of the queue before inserting something into it. This won't work well because SQS cannot give a good estimate until about 1 minute after the producers stop sending to the queue.
- Some sort of distributed lock in the database

Comment: how do you get the quota limit replenished? the quota limit is like 100 req/s? 
How many workers do you have?

Comment: Quota limit refreshes over a day. The limit is not time dependend, I could fire off all requests simultaneously and it would still work. Each request has a cost, I cannot exceed that cost over a 24 hour period. Worker count shouldn't matter but at least 2 for now.

For clarification, my quota limit is very high, I just need a good way to shut off the distributor from the worker that isn't some dist lock.